# Jekyll _config.yml include can't access site

Tags: jekyll

My folder looks like this

```
my-blog
  _includes
  _layouts
  _pages
    contact.html
  _posts
  _config.yml
  index.html
```

In _config.yml

```
email: "xxx@yyy"
.
.
.
include: [_pages]
```

In _pages/contact.html

```
---
layout: default
title: Contact
permalink: /contact/
---
{{site.email}}
```

However, it shows **"{{site.email}}"** but not "xxx@yyy"
Am I able to access "site" in the included folders or files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folders that starts with an underscore are special for Jekyll, and unless they are for using something predefined like _data, they will be ignored by Jekyll.

If you rename the _pages folder to pages then Jekyll will process the file and output the email data with the code you were using.

Comment: I found out that a parse my content with markdown so that jekyll ignored it as pure text.

Comment: And using _pages will not cause any problem, but thanks to your suggestion I'd try to avoid that.